# ImportError: No module named wavePWM

Tags: pi-3, python, pigpio

I am trying to generate 6 simultaneous PWMS to run an AC motor. I have gone through the following link [How to create multiple GPIO pwm waveforms that are in sync using pigpio for trapezoidal motor control?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66102/how-to-create-multiple-gpio-pwm-waveforms-that-are-in-sync-using-pigpio-for-trap/67632#67632?newreg=b1988c8c911a4e60bad4e54086f6f36b)

Here I can see that a module named wavePWM have been imported. Can anyone please tell me how to install this module. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear to be the module provided in the [Wave PWM 2](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_wavePWM_py) example that joan links to in [the other answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66109/58316) on that question. The example is a zip file containing a Python file called `wavePWM.py`. I had a brief look and the class provided is definitely the one referred to in the code linked in the other question.

Simply put that in the same directory as your project, and you should be able to import it as expected. Alternatively, you can put the module anywhere in your [PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19917492/6650102) if you'd prefer; this will work just as well.